# Enabling complete Path Logging in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-mvc, log4j

I wrote the following in my log4j.properties file

`log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n`

`log4j.logger.org.springframework.web = TRACE, stdout`

But I'm just getting the init logging. What should I do so as to get detailed logging so as to get the trace whenever i enter a url in my browser.

Comment: Try to change package name from `log4j.logger.org.springframework.web` to just `log4j.logger.org.springframework`

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to log the execution of program :

1) Add log4j dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Add the one Listner class in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

3) Then add log4jConfigLocation in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and then add your log4j properties as follows :

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout
```

4) Go to the particular java file in your application import log4j package
   and then implement your logging mechanism

5) Now you should be able to trace the log